# Get a list of all change packages of a MKS project

Tags: command-line, automation, revision-history, mks, mks-integrity

I am trying to automatize some tasks of MKS Integrity via command line. Since we are forced to use the change package feature, I try to get a list of all change packages of a single MKS project. How can this be achieved?

I already checked the command line references of 'si' and 'im', but I still have no idea how to get such a list. The only thing I already got to work was a list of change packages from 'si rlog'. Here I could parse the output and drop all duplicate entries. But the problem is, that I only get change packages from files, currently available in the project. Change packages affecting deleted files are not included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To look up change packages by project use the following command:

**si viewcps --filter=project:"c:/path_to_project/project.pj"**

Note that the slashes are forward, not backwards like Windows uses.

There are also different fields and formats available, not just the default ones. if you run **man "si viewcps"** at the command prompt, it will give you a list of fields you can use with the optional --fields tag to output additional information.

Output can be modified to limit results to CP type, state, target, etc. **man "si viewcps"** gives details on how to use these options as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. After some trial and error I found out, that in my case, I additionally had to specify the host name. And the project filter had to be given as stated in the graphical user interface, i. e. no sandbox directory, but a project path on the server.